# Sequence prediction: ambiguity in training set

Tags: sequence-analysis

There is a set of sequences (train set), where each element is one or multiple tags:

```
A, B -- A -- Z -- Z, A
B    -- A -- Z -- D
...
```

Given a new sequence:

```
A, B -- A, B -- Z -- F
```

How to determine the probabilities of each of its instances, like:

```
B -- A -- Z -- F    0.65
A -- A -- Z -- F    0.34
A -- B -- Z -- F    0.01
B -- B -- Z -- F    0
```

**N.B.** Let's call $X(X_1, ..., X_n)$ an instance of sequence $S(S_1, ..., S_n)$ iff for each $1 \le i \le n$: $X_i \in S_i$.

**N.B.** Instances of the new sequence could have never occurred in the training set. Still algorithm has to produce a discrete probability distribution.

Comment: To clarify, by "A, B" do you mean that state could be A or B, you can't tell which, or do you mean you actually have examples where it was A and examples where it was B?

Comment: Could be A or B and there is no way to tell which one. (first option of yours)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you obtained the shown probabilities. However, a possibility would be to fit a probabilistic suffix tree to the observed sequences and use the tree to predict the likelihood of the instances of the new sequence.

I illustrate below using the `PST` R package. Since there are 4 instances of your first sequence, I input them as four sequences with each a weight of `.25`.
`PST` automatically accounts for those weights. Also, when defining the state sequence object with the `TraMineR` `seqdef` function, I explicitly provide the alphabet to include the non-observed state `F`:

```
library(PST)
dat <- c("A-A-Z-Z",
         "B-A-Z-Z",
         "A-A-Z-A",
         "B-A-Z-A",
         "B-A-Z-D"
)

weights <- c(.25,.25,.25,.25,1)
alph <- c("A","B","D","Z","F")

s <- seqdef(dat,weights = weights, alphabet=alph)
seqiplot(s) ## i-plot of the instances

## Growing a tree of order L=3
pst <- pstree(s, L=3, ymin=.001)
```

and now we define the 4 instances of the new sequence and predict their distribution as follows

```
newdat <- c("B-A-Z-F",
            "A-A-Z-F",
            "B-B-Z-F",
            "A-B-Z-F"
)
new.s <- seqdef(newdat, alphabet = alphabet(s))
pred <- predict(pst,new.s) ## likelihood of each instance
## Normalize by sum of likelihoods to get distribution of the 4 instances
prob <- as.matrix(round(pred/sum(pred),3))
rownames(prob) <- newdat
prob
##         prob
## B-A-Z-F 0.714
## A-A-Z-F 0.286
## B-B-Z-F 0.000
## A-B-Z-F 0.000
```

For more details about PSTs see [Gabadinho & Ritschard (2016)](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v072i03).

Comment: Nice solution. Can't wait to try it out.